# Is there a way to extract an object pointer from a std::function?

Tags: c++

I've got a class that holds a list of function objects (std::function).  Other classes can add functions to the list and these functions can be bound to member functions of that class.  This is all working fine.  However, I'd like to be able to distinguish when a function is from a different instance of the same class.  Is it possible to extract this information from the function object?

In the code below, for example, in Foo::AddFunc() is it possible to extract the value of the object instance (i.e. b1 or b2) from the function object?

```
class Foo
{
public:

    typedef std::function<void(int)> Func;

    void AddFunc(const Func &func)
    {
        // can i extract b1 or b2 here?
        m_funcs.push_back(func);
    }

    typedef std::vector<Func> Funcs;
    Funcs m_funcs;
};

Foo *g_foo = new Foo();

class Bar
{
public:

    Bar()
    {
        Foo::Func func = std::bind(&Bar::DoStuff, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        g_foo->AddFunc(func);
    }

    void DoStuff(int x)
    {
    }
};

...

Bar *b1 = new Bar();
Bar *b2 = new Bar();
```

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: A difference instance of `Foo` or a different instance of `Bar`?   What are you really trying to do?  (Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: part of motivation to use `std::function`  is to abstract such details away. If you want a functor with accesible members, then you do not have to use `std::function`

Comment: please try to explain why you want to do this. Currently it is not really clear why there is a problem in the first place, because if you don't bind the object to the `std::function` but instead pass the object and the member function pointer seperately then comparing the objects is trivial

Comment: I understand it's trying to abstract the details, and for most of what I'm doing, that's just fine. However, I have a couple of corner cases in my application where it would be nice to maintain separate function lists for each instance of a class (e.g. b1 vs b2). In my implementation Foo is actually a singleton, so I was trying to abstract the need for multiple lists inside Foo. I could pass the parent instance (b1 / b2) as an additional argument to AddFunc, but that seemed redundant since the pointer is actually encapsulated somewhere in the function object.

Comment: It is possible, but is fragile and a bad idea, don't do it.  Find another solution.